# airodump-ng - What are the abbreviations in the WPS column?

Tags: wifi, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng, wps

when using `airodump-ng`; with the `-W` / `--wps` flag enabled,
what are the abbreviations that show up in the new column;
like: `LAB`,`DISP`,`KPAD`,`PBC`, etc..?

It's only briefly mentioned in the manual:

```
  -W, --wps
         Display a WPS column with WPS version, config method(s), 
         AP Setup Locked obtained from APs beacon or probe response (if any).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this site](https://svn.aircrack-ng.org/trunk/manpages/airodump-ng.8) - `man 8 airodump-ng` may work as well:

> This is only displayed when --wps (or -W) is specified. If the
>     AP supports WPS, the first field of the column indicates version
>     supported. The second field indicates WPS config methods (can be more
>     than one method, separated by comma):

```
USB = USB method, 
ETHER = Ethernet, 
LAB = Label, 
DISP = Display, 
EXTNFC = External NFC, 
INTNFC =Internal NFC, 
NFCINTF = NFC Interface, 
PBC = Push Button, 
KPAD = Keypad. 
Locked is displayed when AP setup is locked.
```

A little more detail. Some of these are covered on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup), others on the [Android Developers site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WpsInfo.html):

- For the USB method a flash drive is used to transfer data between the new client device and the access point
- LAB is a label on the device that contains a PIN to be input into the client device
- DISP is when a device generates a PIN and then it is shown on the device
- EXTNFC, INTNFC, NFCINTF require the devices to be placed near each other for near field communication between the devices
- PBC method requires a button to be pushed on the client device and AP (either physical or virtual)
- KPAD is keypad configuration where the pin is entered on the device
- ETHER ? - I am not sure about this one. It could potentially be for devices that for whatever reason do not have a WPS button (they are supposed to, by the standard though) but still support WPS, potentially something like a range extender. Instead of entering in  a PIN somewhere the configuration is done over an Ethernet cable until pairing is complete, then they will work wirelessly.

Comment: Yeah, I actually found that info on a bunch of different sites; but nobody seems to be able to elaborate. Do you know more about it? I mean, a couple of them (i.e. `PBC`) seem fairly obvious, but some others.. not so much.

Comment: @tjt263 I added a little more information.

Comment: Cool, so these are all part of the WPS standard? I thought WPS was just: Press a button on the AP/router, click a button on the client device, maybe enter a PIN number, and that's it; not unlike pairing a couple of Bluetooth devices.

Comment: AFAIK the pin and pushbutton methods are the only standards, but the others are supported.